# Flash - how to make motion tween go in straight lines

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

I have a MovieClip and I want it to have a motion tween which goes up for 10 frames and then right for 10 frames. What I tried was giving the MovieClip a starting and end position (and then those green motion tween lines appeared) and I tried dragging from the middle of the green line but that gives the motion tween a round shape, it isn't a straight vertical and then horizontal line, which is what I want.

Is there any way to create a motion tween which goes straight up (vertical) and then horizontal?

I am using Adobe Flash CS5 and actionscript 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the line tool, you can draw two lines perpendicular to each other (thus forming a right angle). Then, you can copy and paste the line drawing onto your motion tween layer. It will replace your curved path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a key frame (`F6`) in those specific locations with the symbol selected, and then move the symbol to the desired location.

Frame one = key frame `F6` the starting position.
frame 10 = key frame again, and then move to the final "up" position
frame 20 = key frame again and then move to the final "right" position.

Then right click on the timeline and add a Classic Tween between the frames.

Make sure you hit `F8` to convert any shapes to a movie clip before you set the key frames though or you will get tween elements in your library.

Setting a motion path is generally reserved for more specific "flight" of symbols. You can achieve your effect with simple key frame animation and eliminate the motion path all together.